# Let G be a simple graph that is not a forest and has girth ≥5. Prove that the complement of G is Hamiltonian

Tags: graph, hamiltonian-cycle

Let G be a simple graph that is not a forest and has girth ≥5. Prove that the complement of G is Hamiltonian .
girth is the shortest cycle in the graph . and forest is a graph which does not have any cycles. so G has at least one cycle with the minimum length of 5 . i want to prove that complement of G is hamiltonian

Comment: Even if this is on topic for SO (I'd have thought CS would be a better fit), what have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: well i just have an idea , i guess we can use Dirac's theorem( the statement that an n-vertex graph in which each vertex has degree at least n/2 must have a Hamiltonian cycle) , but i'm not sure .